# Android JSON Communication

Tags: java, php, android, json, web-services

I want to perform this query on a PHP server from my Android device:

```
{
    "command": "REGISTER",
    "data": {
        "email": "EMAIL",
        "login": "LOGIN",
        "password": "PASSWORD",
        "language": "USER_LANGUAGE"      
    }
```

```
public class AysnchronousTaskPost extends AsyncTask<String, Long, String> {
    private static final String PATH = "http://alphabravo.com/myapp/api.php";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        InputStream mInputStream;
        String lineString = "";
        String resultString = "";
        StringBuilder mStringBuilder = null;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command","register"));
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email","abc@gmail.com"));
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "abc"));
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1205"));
        nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("language", "en"));

        try {
            HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost mHttpPost = new HttpPost(PATH);
            mHttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList));

            HttpResponse mHttpResponse = mHttpClient.execute(mHttpPost);
            HttpEntity mHttpEntity = mHttpResponse.getEntity();

            StatusLine mStatusLine = mHttpResponse.getStatusLine();

            int statusCodeString = mStatusLine.getStatusCode();

            if (statusCodeString == 200) {

                mInputStream = mHttpEntity.getContent();

                mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(mInputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                while ((lineString = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    mStringBuilder.append(lineString + "/n");

            }

            resultString = mStringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return resultString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

I am getting an empty `BufferedReader.ReadLine()`. Am I creating `mHttpPost` correctly?
I have Also Tried `HTTPget` Method.
but the result is same.Please Help me

I have Checked my php Script on Browser.My PHP Script is working fine .

Comment: Have you tested to make sure that the php script is returning the correct json values?

Comment: yes my php script return values  correctly ,I have already checked this

Comment: Try logging the result of `mInputStream`

Comment: Note that if you are trying to get `json` object in your server side,you are not getting that, because `mHttpPost.setEntity()` send your parameters as `HTTP post` parameters not `json` representation

Comment: then how can i send the JSON parameters and  get the JSON response ,using this 'JSONObject postJsonObject = new JSONObject();'

Comment: You can refer this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241949/sending-json-object-to-webservice-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your key-value pair into content-type **application/json** and then send it to your server.

Try this in asynctask,

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

// Add key/value pairs
data.put("email", email);
data.put("login", login);
data.put("password", password);
data.put("language", language);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("command", command);
json.put("data", data);

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost("http://alphabravo.com/myapp/api.php");

StringEntity se;
se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

// Set HTTP parameters
httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

String receiveJson = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

//use receiveJson as new JSONObject(receiveJson) ot new JSONArray(receiveJson) as per your returned json value
```

Comment: thanks ,I have try this but 'receiveJSON'  is still empty , I am  expecting JSON object in return

Comment: @kami: I am having doubt that your php script does not return anything, just print your incoming json in PHP and put `Log.d("receiveJson", receiveJson)` and see that it will appear in the log or not.

Comment: @kami: can you please tell me at server side in PHP how you obtain and parse json that being sent from android. because now the problem is at server side I guess, because above code works fine, I've used it in my 2-3 projects without any problem.